# embedded browser in MFC and load google map

Tags: google-maps, browser, mfc

I need to load Google Map in a MFC application.

Then I find two way.

First, load static image https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/?hl=en
But I dont like this way.

Another way, embedded browser in my application then loads up html code for showing google maps.

Would you please tell me way to embedded any browser (IE, Firefox, ..) in my MFC application?

And if you find a better way to load google map in MFC, please tell me

Thank you alot.

Answer (score 1):

You can look into [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752046%28VS.85%29.aspx) control through which you can load your Google Maps.